# Adding a variable to insert query in python

Tags: python, psycopg2

The text file I read from is in `csv` with three fields. But then I want to add the `user_id` and `session_id` variables to the INSERT statement such that they get inserted into the `4-column tblUser` table:

```
user_id = 123
session_id = 999
with open(file, 'r') as f:
                data = f.readlines()
                rslt = [line.strip().split(',') for line in data]
                query = "INSERT INTO tblUser (user_id, session_id,  date, time)" \
                "VALUES (%{user_id}, %{session_id},%s,%s,)"
                cur.executemany(query, rslt)
```

Error:

```
list index out of range
```

It appears I cannot substitute the variables (using `%s`). How do I append it to the results and get send to the database?

file: `user.txt`

```
[['2008-10-30', '23:40:27'],['2009-04-05', '06:46:15'],['2009-04-05', '03:59:09']]
```

**EDIT**

Using `rslt = [user_id, session_id] + rslt` results in the following list (with yet another error)

```
['123', '999', ['2008-10-30', '23:40:27'],['2009-04-05', '06:46:15'],['2009-04-05', '03:59:09']]
```

Error:

```
string index out of range
```

Expected output:

```
[ ['123', '999','2008-10-30', '23:40:27'],['123', '999','2009-04-05', '06:46:15'],['123', '999','2009-04-05', '03:59:09']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just passing `rslt` to `cur.executemany()`, which doest contain `user_id` and `session_id`, add them infront of `rslt`:

```
rslt = [line.strip().split(',') for line in data]
rslt = [[user_id, session_id] + item for item in rlst] # add user/session_id to each nested list.
# triple quotes make multiline strings, to get rid of backslash escaping!
query = """
    INSERT INTO tblUser 
        (user_id, session_id,  date, time)
    VALUES 
        (%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
cur.executemany(query, rslt)
```

Btw. in case you want to use a dictionary, the placeholders end with a s: `%(session_id)s`

**Note**: You can just pass one variable to `executemany` which is ether `tuple/list` or `dictionary`, so you cannot mix placeholders.
So ether all placeholders are `%s` or `%(user_id)s, %(session)s`

Comment: Using `rslt = [user_id, session_id] + rslt` also creates an error as in my edit. I changed  query to `"...VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)`

Comment: @super_ask: Edited, i forgot about the nested lists :)